# Python elegant assignment based on True/False values

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

I have a variable I want to set depending on the values in three booleans. The most straight-forward way is an if statement followed by a series of elifs:

```
if a and b and c:
    name = 'first'
elif a and b and not c:
    name = 'second'
elif a and not b and c:
    name = 'third'
elif a and not b and not c:
    name = 'fourth'
elif not a and b and c:
    name = 'fifth'
elif not a and b and not c:
    name = 'sixth'
elif not a and not b and c:
    name = 'seventh'
elif not a and not b and not c:
    name = 'eighth'
```

This is a bit awkward, and I'm wondering if there's a more Pythonic way to handle this problem. A couple of ideas come to mind.

1. Dictionary hack:

   ```
   name = {a and b and c: 'first',
           a and b and not c: 'second',
           a and not b and c: 'third',
           a and not b and not c: 'fourth',
           not a and b and c: 'fifth',
           not a and b and not c: 'sixth',
           not a and not b and c: 'seventh',
           not a and not b and not c: 'eighth'}[True]
   ```

I call it a hack because I'm not too wild about seven of the keys being False and overriding each other.

1. And/or magic

   ```
   name = (a and b and c and 'first' or
           a and b and not c and 'second' or
           a and not b and c and 'third' or
           a and not b and not c and 'fourth' or
           not a and b and c and 'fifth' or
           not a and b and not c and 'sixth' or
           not a and not b and c and 'seventh' or
           not a and not b and not c and 'eighth')
   ```

This works because Python ands and ors return the last value to be evaluated, but you have to know that in order to understand this otherwise bizarre code.

None of these three options is very satisfying. What do you recommend?

Comment: Another drawback of #2: It fail when one of the values to be mapped to is falsy (e.g. 0).

Comment: +1 for a practical code golf :)

Comment: it seems some have read 'first', 'second' as arbitrary placeholders, while other read them as the actual strings you need to produce.  I'm curious - could you please shed light on this?

Comment: They are placeholders indicating a general case.

Answer (score 50):

You can think of a, b, and c as three bits that when put together form a number between 0 and 7.  Then, you can have an array of the values ['first', 'second', ... 'eighth'] and use the bit value as an offset into the array.  This would just be two lines of code (one to assemble the bits into a value from 0-7, and one to lookup the value in the array).

Here's the code:

```
nth = ['eighth', 'seventh', 'sixth', 'fifth', 'fourth', 'third', 'second', 'first']
nth[(a and 4 or 0) | (b and 2 or 0) | (c and 1 or 0)]
```

Comment: +1 exactly what I was thinking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726949/python-elegant-assignment-based-on-true-false-values/4727158#4727158  :P But It took me a while to know how to write the ternary operator in python.  I used something like this for this FizzBuzz solution in Java : http://rosettacode.org/wiki/FizzBuzz#Using_an_array :)

Comment: Couldn't you drop the `or 0` parts?

Comment: Sven, probably so.  My Python is a bit rusty. :-)

Comment: @Clint:  That's not related to Python in any way I think :)

Comment: @Sven it is, and yes, that's possible: `nth[(a and 4)|( b and 2)|(c and 1)]` works well.

Comment: @Sven, it has to do with treating false as a synonym for 0.  That won't work in Ruby and Haskell (the 2 languages I've been doing most of my work in the last couple of years). :-)

Comment: @Clint Nor Java where booleans and numbers don't mix.

Comment: If you leave off the `or 0`, then it will break if you have anything that evaluates to false but `0` or `False` (that don't support bitwise or)

Comment: I believe cleaner version of `(a and 4 or 0)` is `(4 if a else 0)`. It looks more obvious. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 30):

How about using a dict?

```
name = {(True, True, True): "first", (True, True, False): "second",
        (True, False, True): "third", (True, False, False): "fourth",
        (False, True, True): "fifth", (False, True, False): "sixth",
        (False, False, True): "seventh", (False, False, False): "eighth"}

print name[a,b,c] # prints "fifth" if a==False, b==True, c==True etc.
```

Comment: +1 exactly what I did when confronted with something very similar. With a comment `# first boolean means x, second means y, third means z` of course. (You got the lookup syntax wrong in the last line, should be `print name[(a,b,c)]` or `print name[a,b,c]`).

Comment: @delnan: Thanks, I noticed that, too - and I hadn't thought about dropping the parens around the tuple. Nice that it works without them. Tuple packing/unpacking, huh?

Comment: No, it's not tuple unpacking.  Tuples don't need parentheses, except some ambiguity arises by omitting them.

Comment: Nope, no packing/unpacking. The comma constructs tuples, parens are only *needed* sometimes for precedence (they add clarity in many other cases, but not here - double brackets are a visual pain to me).

Comment: This is the fastest algorithm!

Comment: Note that this is the only solution that requires `a`, `b` and `c` really to be `bools`.  All other solutions so far implicitly convert to `bool`.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: Yes, as specified in the question. But good to point this out.

Comment: @Sven: that's not true. They can also be integers, did you mean to say, that it work correctly with any trucy or falsy object?

Comment: +1 Simple is better than complex. Encoding the bits as a int may seem clever, but in the end it's just a unnecessary additional step.

Comment: We've got some algorithm wars going on here! :-)  I think both solutions are fine.  I'm surprised that this hash-based solution involving building a tuple and a hash lookup is faster than a bitwise operation and an index into an array.  But, if that's what the data says, so be it.  (I haven't timed it.)  But, I would say that if timing is so critical to you that one of these algorithms performs ok and the other is too slow, you should probably be writing in C instead of Python. :-)

Comment: Also, I wouldn't consider the bitwise or-ing algorithm to be particularly clever or particularly obscure.  It's a pretty common approach to problems like this, and it recognizes the fact that the problem is just mimicking a MUX.  It's just taking a common item like a MUX (that every programmer should be familiar with) and using it as a model.

Comment: The problem with this approach, is the code grows considerably if you add a new condition ( a, b, c, d ) You'll have to type the 16 combinations :-/

Comment: @OzcarRyz if it grows, I'd consider binary to generate keys when *building* the table, but leave the lookup structure as is.  It's really the natural data structure for this.

Comment: @OscarRyz Some effort to spell out the table could be saved with itertools. Example: `name = dict(zip(itertools.product(*[[True, False]]*3), ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth']))`

Answer (score 11):

Maybe not much better, but how about

```
results = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 
           'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth']
name = results[((not a) << 2) + ((not b) << 1) + (not c)]
```

Comment: @SilentGhost:  I always get confused with operator precedence -- added the missing parens :)

Comment: Very obfuscated code imo. I know why it works, but it's too clever. (Edit @Sven: It used to have a problem, as SilentGhost noted)

Comment: Not my downvote, but it's hard to read and highly magick. I'd definitely recommend against this if anyone else is ever supposed to read the code.

Comment: @Lennart:  I would also recommend against using this as a general pattern, but I actually never came across something like this in real code :)

Comment: -1 for inverting the bits.  ` bool(a)` would be better (making "first" be last but better be explicit about it than tweak the encoding).  Priority tip: `|` plays nice with `<<`, unlike`+`, and is also more natural for this.

Comment: @Beni - you're specifically choosing the bitfield assignments of a,b,c anyway to generate the index, so I think that inverting them makes sense given the results (1st, 2nd, etc).

Comment: Strange, this reads fine to me. I think it is clever, but not overly clever or dangerous sorcery. +1.

Comment: @TimPost: I don't understand this as well.  This is one of the biggest number of downvotes I ever got, and I posted the code before Clint :)

Comment: @Peter Gibson: the One Trivial way to map several bits into numbers is 000=0, 001=1, 010=2...; anything else requires the reader to compose two non-trivial mappings in his head.  I'm assuming 'first' etc. were just arbitrary placeholders, used by the OP according to his order of conditionals (which is backwards, I'd -1 him them too).  But if he really needs "first" etc. as his answer then I'd say the trivial half of the mapping is 1="first",2="second"... and the non-trivial part should indeed be the formula (8-4*a-2*b-c).

Answer (score 5):

if a,b,c are really booleans:

```
li = ['eighth', 'seventh', 'sixth', 'fifth', 'fourth', 'third', 'second', 'first']
name = li[a*4 + b*2 + c]
```

if they are not booleans:

```
li = ['eighth', 'seventh', 'sixth', 'fifth', 'fourth', 'third', 'second', 'first']
a,b,c = map(bool,(a,b,c))
name = li[a*4 + b*2 + c]
```

idea from Clint Miller

Answer (score 2):

Since your getting all the combinations, you could create an index based on the values like this:

```
def value(a,b,c ): 
   values = ['8th','7th','6th','5th','4th','3rd','2nd','1st']
   index = ( 4 if a else 0 ) + ( 2 if b else 0 ) + ( 1 if c else 0 )
   return values[index]

if __name__ == "__main__":
   print value(True,  True,  True )
   print value(True,  True,  False )
   print value(True,  False, True )
   print value(True,  False, False )
   print value(False, True,  True )
   print value(False, True,  False)
   print value(False, False, True )
   print value(False, False, False)
```

output:

```
1st
2nd
3rd
4th
5th
6th
7th
8th
```

Answer (score 1):

What about nested ifs - it means you don't have to check everything several times and reads clearer to me (although maybe not quite as clever as some of the other answers):

```
if a:
    if b:
        if c:
            name="first"
        else:
            name="second"
    else:
        if c:
            name="third"
        else:
            name="fourth"
else:
    if b:
        if c:
            name="fifth"
        else:
            name="sixth"
    else:
        if c:
            name="seventh"
        else:
            name="eighth"
```

Comment: +1: not clever, but the most readable. at least you understand what's going on without scratching your head.

Comment: I'm not downvoting, but I think it's horrible. I think clint's solution plus a good comment is the best

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to create a helper function:

```
def first_true(*args):
    true_vals = (arg for arg in args if arg[0])
    return next(true_vals)[1]

name = first_true((a and b and c, 'first'),
                  (a and b and not c, 'second'),
                  (a and not b and c, 'third'),
                  (a and not b and not c, 'fourth'),
                  (not a and b and c, 'fifth'),
                  (not a and b and not c, 'sixth'),
                  (not a and not b and c, 'seventh'),
                  (not a and not b and not c, 'eighth'))
```

This method assumes that one of the tests passed in will be true. It could also be made lazier with lambdas.

Comment: My apologies, late night, no excuse but still.

Answer (score 1):

To measure speeds:

```
from time import clock
a,b,c = True,False,False

A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H = [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]


for j in xrange(30):


    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(10000):
        name = (a and b and c and 'first' or
                a and b and not c and 'second' or
                a and not b and c and 'third' or
                a and not b and not c and 'fourth' or
                not a and b and c and 'fifth' or
                not a and b and not c and 'sixth' or
                not a and not b and c and 'seventh' or
                not a and not b and not c and 'eighth')
    A.append(clock()-te)



    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(10000):
        if a and b and c:
            name = 'first'
        elif a and b and not c:
            name = 'second'
        elif a and not b and c:
            name = 'third'
        elif a and not b and not c:
            name = 'fourth'
        elif not a and b and c:
            name = 'fifth'
        elif not a and b and not c:
            name = 'sixth'
        elif not a and not b and c:
            name = 'seventh'
        elif not a and not b and not c:
            name = 'eighth'
    B.append(clock()-te)

    #=====================================================================================

    li = ['eighth', 'seventh', 'sixth', 'fifth', 'fourth', 'third', 'second', 'first']
    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(10000):
        name = li[a*4 + b*2 + c]
    C.append(clock()-te)

    #=====================================================================================

    nth = ['eighth', 'seventh', 'sixth', 'fifth', 'fourth', 'third', 'second', 'first']
    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(10000):
        name = nth[(a and 4 or 0) | (b and 2 or 0) | (c and 1 or 0)]
    D.append(clock()-te)


    nth = ['eighth', 'seventh', 'sixth', 'fifth', 'fourth', 'third', 'second', 'first']
    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(10000):
        name = nth[(a and 4 or 0) + (b and 2 or 0) + (c and 1 or 0)]
    E.append(clock()-te)

    #=====================================================================================

    values = ['eighth', 'seventh', 'sixth', 'fifth', 'fourth', 'third', 'second', 'first']
    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(10000):
        name = values[( 4 if a else 0 )| ( 2 if b else 0 ) | ( 1 if c else 0 )]
    F.append(clock()-te)


    values = ['eighth', 'seventh', 'sixth', 'fifth', 'fourth', 'third', 'second', 'first']
    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(10000):
        name = values[( 4 if a else 0 ) + ( 2 if b else 0 ) + ( 1 if c else 0 )]
    G.append(clock()-te)

    #=====================================================================================

    dic = {(True, True, True): "first",
           (True, True, False): "second",
           (True, False, True): "third",
           (True, False, False): "fourth",
           (False, True, True): "fifth",
           (False, True, False): "sixth",
           (False, False, True): "seventh",
           (False, False, False): "eighth"}
    te = clock()
    for i in xrange(10000):
        name = dic[a,b,c]
    H.append(clock()-te)




print min(A),'\n', min(B),'\n\n', min(C),'\n\n', min(D),'\n',min(E),'\n\n',min(F),'\n', min(G),'\n\n', min(H)
```

Result

```
0.0480533140385 
0.0450973517584 

0.0309056039245 

0.0295291720037 
0.0286550385594 

0.0280122194301 
0.0266760160858 

0.0249769174574
```

Comment: If the object creation happens as often as the query (such as: both once) and is included in the measure, then the second option (the `if`s) is by far the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for the list/bits solution of @OscarRyz, @Clint and @Sven, but here's another one:

```
S1 = frozenset(['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth'])
S2 = frozenset(['first', 'second', 'fifth', 'sixth'])
S3 = frozenset(['first', 'third', 'fifth', 'seventh'])
last = 'eighth'
empty = frozenset([])
```

def value(a, b, c):
    for r in (a and S1 or empty) & (b and S2 or empty) & (c and S3 or empty):
        return r
    return last

Comment: did you actually test anything to say that dictionary is the least efficient? I have and on my machine tim's solution is much faster than either sven's or clint's.

Comment: No, it was just a mere estimation. I think you're right and tim's solution being faster. I probably had in mind the other "dictionary solution" when i wrote that. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if your goal is to avoid writing a lot of "ands" and boolean expressions you can use prime number and only one conditions like this (example for 2 conditions)

```
 cond = (2**cond_1)*(3**cond_2)
```

so

```
cond == 1 #means cond_1 and cond_2 are False
cond == 2 #means cond_1 is True and con_2 is False
cond == 3 #means cond_1 is False and con_2 is True
cond == 6 #means con_1 and Con_2 are True
```

This hack can be used for 3 conditions using 3 primes and so on

Like this...

```
cond = (2**a)*(3**b)*(5**c)
name = {30:'first', 6: 'second', 10:'third', 2:'fourth',
        15:'fifth', 3:'sixth', 5:'seventh', 1:'eighth'}[cond]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a truth table approach:

```
lookup = {'000': 'eighth',
          '001': 'seventh',
          '010': 'sixth',
          '011': 'fifth',
          '100': 'fourth',
          '101': 'third',
          '110': 'second',
          '111': 'first'}

def key(a, b, c):
    return ''.join([str(a),str(b),str(c)])

name = lookup[key(0,1,1)]
```