# How to write If statements for all 2^N boolean conditions (python)

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a function which needs to execute a query based on the query instances inputted.. 
but as the conditions are increasing it is becoming tedious for me to list all of them.
For example:
suppose i have two conditions initially:

```
if (cond_1 == True and cond_2 == False):
    do something
elif  cond_1 == True and cond_2 == True:
    do something else
elif cond_1 == False and cond_2 == True:
    do this
```

....

so I guess if conditions takes on binary values then there are 2^n statements i have to write :(

so now i have 3 condition variables (8 statements).. and i am afraid that this number might increase in future.
Is tehre a better way to check these conditions??

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726949/python-elegant-assignment-based-on-true-false-values

Comment: If you want to do something else in all of these cases, then there is now way around writing a statement for every of the cases, right?

Comment: `== True` and `== False` almost always a (stylistic) mistake.  Use `cond_1 and not cond_2)` etc.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: actually there is a slight variation in what is executed inside the loops.. as it is generally a query.. so if condition is true.. then it includes teh condition value in the query else excludes it from the query.. (SQL queries.. Select * from this If cond = this and cond_2 = that.. so the basic structure is kinda common. but based on loops those conditions are appended

Comment: You should give an example what you are doing in the individual cases -- chances are this can be done easier.

Comment: 'pythonic' should not be used as a synonym for best. 'pythonic' means the method most approved by the Python developers. What is best is entirely subjective.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do you need to always write all all 2^n possibilities?

And are all things you have to do different (so also 2^n actions?)

However I can give some hints:

Don't use '== True' or '== False'

What you wrote equals:

```
if cond_1 and not cond_2:
    do something 
elif cond_1 and cond_2:
    do something else 
elif not cond_1 and cond_2:
    do this
```

Also think about writing:

```
if cond_1:
    if cond_2:
        Do something
    else:
        Do something 
else:
    if cond_2:
        Do something
    else:
        Do something
```

You also can define functions depending on the values:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.actions = {
      (False, False): action_1,
      (False, True ): action_2,
      ...
    }

def action_1(self):
    some action

def action_2(self):
    some action

....
```

and call it with:

```
self.actions[(cond_1, cond_2)]()
```

If you want to optimize the number of options in case you have different conditions with similar actions, take a look to Karnaugh Maps (it is easier than it looks like):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

Comment: NICE tip on K-maps, never even thought of them (it's been a loong time since I've seen them).

Comment: Karnaugh map = 1rst year CS nightmare

Comment: Actually I like those maps ... very simple and fun to simplify complex boolean expressions.

Answer (score 7):

You should [never test a boolean variable with `== True` or `== False`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/12807/make-a-big-deal-out-of-true). Instead, just using the boolean values is enough. If you want to cover virtually every combination of truth values, you may also want to nest, like this:

```
if cond_1:
    if cond_2:
        do something
    else:
        do something else
elif cond_2:
    do this
```

If the number increases further than that, I'd suggest a map, like this:

```
call_map = {
  (True, True, True): func1,
  (True, False, True): func2,
  (True, False, False): func3,
}
try:
  func = call_map[(cond_1, cond_2, cond_3)]
except KeyError:
  pass
else:
  func()
```

However, note that a large number of distinct cases is a sure code smell. In virtually any situation, you don't actually need so many cases, and can actually call a function directly. You may think your case is an exception, but chances are it is not. Why do you need that many cases?

Comment: "You should never test a boolean variable with == True or == False" -- in addition to readability/style concerns, it's also safer to omit the explicit mentions of True and False the comparison.  Saying `if x == True` is testing if the value of x is equal to the value of the object reference named `True` (which could be redefined, though __*extremely*__ bad practice to do so). Saying `if x:` is testing if x evaluated in a boolean context evaluates to the boolean value True (which is *exactly* what is intended).

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for a compact way to write out a truth table. (Your only other alternative is to find a way to simplify your expressions using boolean algebra; a simplified form may not exist.) There is no way to make this simpler except to save on typing:

```
def TruthTable(text):
    table = {}

    for line in text.splitlines():
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            inputs,output = line.split()
            table[tuple(bool(int(x)) for x in inputs)] = bool(int(output))

    return lambda *inputs:table[inputs]
```

Demo:

```
myFunc = TruthTable('''
    000 1
    001 0
    010 0
    011 1
    100 1
    101 0
    110 0
    111 1
''')
```

Output:

```
>>> myFunc(False, False, True)
False
```

---

If you need more than boolean outputs, you can adapt this to refer to arbitrary expressions by using for example a dictionary, and post-processing the keys into tuples of booleans:

```
{
    (0,0,0): <expr0>,
    (0,0,1): <expr1>,
    (0,1,0): <expr2>,
    (0,1,1): <expr3>,
    ...
}
```

You could also do it as follows with binary notation (e.g. `0b110 == 6`) but I find it much less clean:

```
{
    0b000: <expr0>,
    0b001: <expr1>,
    ...
}
```

You could even just use a list which you later convert into a dictionary for quick lookup (by doing `dict((intToBinarytuple(i),expr) for i,expr enumerate(myList))`):

```
[
             # ABC
    <expr0>, # 000
    <expr1>, # 001
    <expr2>, # 010
    <expr3>, # 011
    ...
]
```

---

**sidenote**: In the unlikely event you need arbitrary python commands, you can dispatch like so:

```
conditions = (True, False, True)

c = lambda *args: conditions==toBooleanTuple(args)
if c(0,0,0):
    ...
elif c(0,0,1):
    ...
elif c(0,1,0):
    ...
elif c(0,1,1):
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use a dict to map the conditions to the action in a clearer way.  If you really need to do something different for each case, then there probably isn't any better way than just enumerating the possibilities.

```
def do_something():
  pass

def do_something_else():
  pass

def do_this():
  pass


do_dict = {(True, False): do_something, 
           (True, True): do_something_else,
           (False, True): do_this}

# call it
do_dict[(cond_1, cond_2)]()
```

Answer (score 4):

if your goal is to avoid writing a lot of "ands" and boolean expressions you can use prime number and only one conditions like this (example for 2 conditions)

```
 cond = (2**cond_1)*(3**cond_2)
```

so

```
cond == 1 #means cond_1 and cond_2 are False
cond == 2 #means cond_1 is True and con_2 is False
cond == 3 #means cond_1 is False and con_2 is True
cond == 6 #means con_1 and Con_2 are True
```

This hack can be used for 3 conditions using 3 primes and so on

Comment: You're right, I'm wrong, my bad :( Guess this means I should stop moderating for tonight. Sorry about that, both questions restored and (now) misleading comments removed.

Comment: sorry my point was that you can generalize with primes to any number of condition without much effort, sorry if anything, let me know what you decide and if i am wrong.

Comment: No, I was wrong, I confused the use of multiplication with addition, I was thinking along the lines of the binary values example. Yours is pretty much the same, but also different, so it has merit. Forget I ever drove my nose into your two answers :)

Answer (score 3):

You can take an n-sized list of conditions, and convert it into a single value for comparison, by converting the conditions into sums of multiples of 2.

```
>>> conditions = [True, False, True, True, False]
>>> condition = sum(2**i * cond for i, cond in enumerate(conditions))
>>> condition
13
```

First value of condition is `2^0 = 1`, second is `2^1 = 2`, third is `2^2 = 4`, ... which are each multiplied by the truth value (1 if `True`, 0 if `False`).

This also allows you to see if a subset of the conditions are true.  If you need to know if at least a subset of the conditions are true, you can use a binary `&` to find out:

```
>>> subset = lambda c, x: (c & x) == x
>>> conditions = [True, False, True, True, False, True, True, True, True]
>>> condition = sum(2**i * cond for i, cond in enumerate(conditions))
>>> subset(condition, 13)
True
>>> subset(condition, 2)
False
```

To have the features provided by some of the previous answers, instead of using a dictionary, you could also use both a list and a dict to map conditions to actions.  You can also implement `defaultdict`-like functionality with a list (though this uses 2^n memory, and probably isn't the best idea):

```
def do_something():
    print("Hello World!")
condition_action_map = [None] * (2 ** len(conditions))
condition_action_map[13] = do_something
```

You would probably want to comment this thoroughly if you were using something like this.